# Ruby - receive multiple lines on network socket

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm writing a basic network logging script where a client can connect to my server socket, and all data read from the socket will be written to file.

I have it so I can connect with telnet and the first line (before enter is pressed) is written to file, but subsequent lines are not being written. What do I need to change to make this work properly?

I also want to be able to have multiple listening sockets writing to the same file - is there a way to do this without multi-threading?

```
log_path ||= "./network-logs"
listen_port ||= 2509
minute_buffer = {now: Time.now, buffer: "" }
current_time = Time.now
current_date = Date.today.to_s
client = nil
Dir.mkdir(log_path) unless File.exists?(log_path)
f = File.new("#{log_path}/#{current_date}.txt", 'w')

def short_time
  "%02d" % Time.now.hour.to_s + ':' + 
  "%02d" % Time.now.min.to_s + ':' + 
  "%02d" % Time.now.sec.to_s
end

server = TCPServer.open(listen_port)
loop {                                  
  client = server.accept                
  f.puts "#{Time.now} Client Connected"
  puts "#{Time.now} Client Connected"
  current_time = Time.now               
  if minute_buffer[:now].min != Time.now.min 
    f.puts "##### Minute summary for #{minute_buffer[:now].to_s}: #{minute_buffer[:min]} :"
    puts "##### Minute summary for #{minute_buffer[:now].to_s}: #{minute_buffer[:min]} :"
    f.puts "##### #{minute_buffer[:buffer]}"
    minute_buffer[:now] = Time.now
    minute_buffer[:buffer] = ""
  end
  data = client.gets
  f.puts short_time + "  : " + data.to_s
  puts short_time + "  : " + data.to_s
  minute_buffer[:buffer] = minute_buffer[:buffer] + data.to_s
  if current_date != Date.today.to_s
    f.close
    current_date = Date.today.to_s
    f = File.new("#{log_path}/#{current_date}.txt", 'w')
  end
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the `client = server.accept` line out of the loop:

```
...
server = TCPServer.open(listen_port)
client = server.accept # <- moved out of the loop
loop {                                  
  f.puts "#{Time.now} Client Connected"
...
```

Comment: That f.puts line will also have to be moved outside the loop, otherwise it'll be listed many thousands of times for one lot of data, because there would no longer be a wait function in the loop.
It also causes the issue that any time this script was run, it would only be good for a single connection. Though, that said, doing it that way and having all of that in an outer loop with exception handling to deal with a client disconnect and hence not having data to read at `client.gets` wouldn't cause an issue. Will experiment and update my question.